# callback javascript postMessage ios swift

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, xcode

Please tell me, there is an ios application, it contains WebKitView, and in it there is a site with this code:

```
<div id="test" style="height: 40px; width: 100px; background-color: powderblue;">Hello</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("click", function () {
   window.webkit.messageHandlers.test.postMessage("TEXT");
});
</script>
```

Application Code:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit
class ViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate, WKScriptMessageHandler {
    
    var webView: WKWebView!
    
    override func loadView() {
        webView = WKWebView()
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        view = webView
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let url = URL(string: "https://site")!
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
        let config: WKWebViewConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        config.userContentController.add(self, name: "test")
        webView = WKWebView(frame: self.view.frame, configuration: config)
        webView?.navigationDelegate = self
        self.webView?.load(URLRequest(url:url))
    }

    
    func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
        if message.name == "test", let messageBody = message.body as? String {
            print(messageBody)
        }
    }
}
```

When you click on the div in xcode, the following error is displayed in the log

```
[general] Connection to daemon was invalidated
```

What could be the problem?
Sorry for my English.

Comment: This bug is not related to div click actually. Try adding webView on the main view as a subview. Also, Why are you loading the URL request two times? Do it after adding configuration and load it in main thread.

Comment: @ShashankMishra Can you please fix my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've added the shared HTML & javascript code in the main bundle as "example.html" and made changes in your code. It is working fine at my end.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //Url from the html
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "example", ofType: "HTML") ?? "")
        
        // Configuring WKEWebview
        let config: WKWebViewConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        config.userContentController.add(self, name: "test")
        webView = WKWebView(frame: self.view.frame, configuration: config)
        webView?.navigationDelegate = self
        
        //Constraints related changes
        webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
        webView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

        self.view.addSubview(self.webView)
        // Load file
        self.webView?.loadFileURL(url, allowingReadAccessTo: Bundle.main.bundleURL)
    }
```

You can load your webpage using

```
self.webView.load(URLRequest(url: "https://www.site"))
```

Try it and let me know if you face any issue.